# Tannaka–Krein duality in non-compact case

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, locally-compact-groups

The [Tannaka–Krein duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tannaka%E2%80%93Krein_duality) provides a way to reconstruct a group (up to isomorphisms) from the category of linear representations of that group.

In physics, this duality is sometimes used as a justification for considering only linear representations in some context (e.g. when classifying elementary particles, see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/551961/257225)).

However, the duality as explained in Wikipedia is for compact groups and groups considered in physics are not compact (e.g. [Poincaré group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_group) and its cover), only locally-compact.

What does this duality say in the non-compact case?